# Change root bone position in animation

Tags: animation, armature, bones

I need to correct a root bone in someone else's model so that it is at zero (height) during animation.

Initially it looks like in the first image. I have set the position to zero using the edit mode (image 2), but it is still offset in the animation.

[image]

[image]

Can you tell me how to remove this offset (as in image 3) without moving the whole armature along with it?

[image]

I'm not into Blender myself, I need this for Unreal. I tried separating the bone and setting the height to zero in the animation, but apparently that's not how it's done.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we want to re-evaluate bones in some other space-- ie, with a root in some other location-- we can do it by creating a few constraints and using a "bake action" operation.

Start by duplicating your armature (with the same action.)  Give the duplicate's root bone a "limit location" constraint.  Here, where you say you are interested in preventing it from moving up or down only, you can do this by putting the limit location constraint in local space, limiting only Z axis location to 0-0.  This will clamp the root bone to its rest XY plane.

Now, give bones in the next level of your hierarchy-- bones that are parented to the root-- copy transforms constraints targeting their counterparts in your original armature.  Leave these constraints at their default world->world settings.

Now, use a bake action operation on your duplicated armature, with "visual keying" and "clear constraints" (actually, I think clear constraints is optional in this case, but it's generally what you want for this kind of retargeting.)  You end up with an animation where the root is clamped to its rest XY plane, but its children are where they would be, if it were following the original animation.

Comment: Thanks for your response. How can I target a bone of first armature in `copy transform` constraint? As I understand It requires a target Data ID which cannot be set manually and from options I have only armatures and meshes.

Comment: Set the appropriate armature in the field, and a new field will open which will allow you to designate a bone in that armature.  Make sure you are making a bone constraint and not an object constraint.

Comment: You were right! I had to add two more constraints to make it work the way I wanted, but that was what I was looking for. Thanks.

The only thing I didn't understand is why the constants are reset after the animation is baked. So I have to bake the action, copy, go back, save and so on for all the animations.

Comment: @Vaidual Because that's what "clear constraints" does.  But, it doesn't matter, because it's also baking the action of all constraints into the action, which is what "visual keying" does.  There are a number of options here if you need something specific, like, maybe, baking only the selected bones; you could copy/paste keyframes between actions as well.